# Java pass by value with recursion

Tags: java, oop, recursion, parameter-passing, binary-search-tree

The following is a simple implementation of Binary search tree using java. However, the code always outputs "BST empty!!" despite inserting elements. Where am I going wrong? I suspect I'm going wrong with recursion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    NODE root;
    BinarySearchTree(){
        root = null;
    }
    void insert(NODE nodeptr,int key){
        if(root == null){
            nodeptr = new NODE(key);
            return;
        }
        if(nodeptr == null){
            nodeptr = new NODE(key);
            return;
        }
        if(key <= nodeptr.data){
            insert(nodeptr.left,key);
        }
        else{
            insert(nodeptr.right,key);
        } 

    }

    void inorder(NODE nodeptr){
        if(nodeptr == null){
            System.out.println("BST empty!!");
            return;
        }
        inorder(nodeptr.left);
        System.out.println(nodeptr.data + " ");
        inorder(nodeptr.right);

    }
    /*driver program*/
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] a = {20,30,40,24,39};
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
        for (int i: a){
            bst.insert(bst.root,i);
        }
        bst.inorder(bst.root);
    }
}

class NODE{
    int data;
    NODE left,right;
    NODE(int data){
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the following code snippet (inside your `insert` method) does: `nodeptr = new NODE(key); return;`?

Comment: Assigning to a variable passed in as a parameter doesn't affect the variable used as an argument to the method. I.e. passing `bst.root` into `bst.insert` does not reassign `bst.root`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `insert` method never assigns value to the root, so it remains null.

If I understand your code, your insert should look like this :

```
void insert(NODE nodeptr,int key){
    if(root == null){
        root = new NODE(key);
        return;
    }
    if(nodeptr == null){
        insert (root, key);
        return;
    }
    if(key <= nodeptr.data){
        if (nodeptr.left != null)
            insert(nodeptr.left,key);
        else
            nodeptr.left = new NODE(key);
    }
    else{
        if (nodeptr.right != null)
            insert(nodeptr.right,key);
        else
            nodeptr.right = new NODE(key);
    } 

}
```

- If the `root` is null, ignore the passed `nodeptr` and put `key` at the root of the tree.
- If `nodeptr` is null, try to insert the new key starting at the root of the tree.
- otherwise, once you find a null `nodeptr.left` or `nodeptr.right`, you must put the new `key` there, because if you make another recursive call, you would be passing a null Node to it, and the recursion would never end.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding from Erans answer you could change it to:

```
public void insert(int key){
    if(root == null){
        root = new NODE(key);
        return;
    }
    insert(root,key)
  }

private void insert(NODE nodeptr,int key){
    if(key <= nodeptr.data){
        if(nodeptr.left == null){
           nodeptr.left = new NODE(key)
        }
        else {
            insert(nodeptr.left,key);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(nodeptr.right == null){
           nodeptr.right = new NODE(key)
        }
        else {
            insert(nodeptr.right,key);
        }
    } 
}
```

Edit: As he has added his own code now its just a matter of what style you like better. A single method or two methods from which the public one has only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my insert method something like this. Got it to working finally. Thank you all for your precious time.

```
NODE insert(NODE nodeptr,int key){
        if(nodeptr == null){
            nodeptr = new NODE(key);
        }
        else if(key <= nodeptr.data){
            nodeptr.left = insert(nodeptr.left,key);
        }
        else{
            nodeptr.right = insert(nodeptr.right,key);
        } 
        return nodeptr;

    }
```

I would call insert method from main something like this:

```
bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root,i);
```